# How do I preview my android app on a device? (It's connected via usb to my Mac.)

Tags: android

(Sorry, not sorry for the noob question)

I'm making my first Android. I'm going [through this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app) on the Android Developers site and it says to open the "Settings" from the "Developer Options" but there is no context ... I can't find the Developer Options when I browse through the menus or search in Help... Where is this fabled "Settings" app?

I'm trying to let it know that my Pixel is attached by USB. Where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some hidden actions to enable developer option.
Refer this link https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Comment: Please do not post answers that mainly consist of a link. You should quote the relevant information in your answer additionally.

Comment: That's helpful! I figured it out, but that screenshot of a device should be on the main tutorial. Thanks!!

Comment: Now I can't figure out how to add the configuration to the run/debug menu in Android Studio... the screenshot in the tutorial seems outdated.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 4.1 and lower, the Developer options screen is available by default. On Android 4.2 and higher, you must enable this screen as follows [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options):

1. Open the **Settings** app.
2. (Only on Android 8.0 or higher) Select **System**.
3. Scroll to the bottom and select **About phone**.
4. Scroll to the bottom and tap **Build number** 7 times.
5. Return to the previous screen to find **Developer options** near the bottom.

Comment: figured it out, the instructions leave out that the settings app is the one on your phone, not in Android Studio. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is that I was looking for a settings app on my Mac, not on my phone... Figured it out.

[image]

Comment: what a strange, strange way to activate developer mode on a device. Is this somebody's idea of an inside joke? Context please.